# Stack of cards and the game of War

Tags: c, stack

So i am making the card game called War, the rules are the following:

1. Player 1 and player 2 each queues of cards called q1 and q2. Both
   queues are not empty. The players also have empty battle stacks s1
   and s2.
2. Each player removes a card from the front of their queue and puts it
   on the top of their stack
3. If the cards have equal face values, a war happens.
4. Each player moves 3 additional cards from their queue to their stack
   and check the face value of their top cards again. This may happen
   several times. Go to 3 again.
5. If the cards do not have equal values, the battle has ended and a
   can be determined.

the function i have to write is called start_battle.c and the logic i have came up with is the following, the `queue_front`, `queue_empty` and `stack_top` functions are already written. So my pseudocode is the following:

```
function start_battle(q1, q2, s1, s2, logfile)

warc=0
move front card of q1 to the top of s1
move front card of q2 to the top of s2
while (top cards of s1 and s2 have equal value
       and both q1 and q2 are not empty)           
  for i=1 to 3
    if q1 is not empty
      move front card of q1 to the top of s1
    endif
  done
  for i=1 to 3
    if q2 is not empty
      move front card of q2 to the top of s2
    endif
  done
done
return warc
```

My code is the following:

```
#include "libcardlist.h"
int start_battle(queue *q1, queue *q2, stack *s1, stack *s2, FILE *logfile){    
    int warc =0;
    int i;
    stack_push(s1, queue_front(q1));
    stack_push(s2, queue_front(q2));
    card c1 = stack_top(s1);
    card c2 = stack_top(s2);
    while (c1.face==c2.face&&  queue_empty(q1)==0 && queue_empty(q2)==0) {        
        warc++;        
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if(queue_empty(q1)==0){
                stack_push(s1, queue_front(q1));
            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if (queue_empty(q2)==0){
              stack_push(s2, queue_front(q2));
            }    
        }       
   }
   return warc;
}
```

oh and

```
typedef struct {
  int face;         /* 2-14 */
  char suit;            /* C H S D */
} card;
```

When i test it, my code is stuck in the while loop, can someone help me fix it?

Comment: Does `queue_front()` actually remove cards from the queue?

Comment: queue_front() just gets the data of the front of the queue.

Comment: Then you need to remove it otherwise you have the card in both piles.

Comment: they are 2 different cards, of 2 stacks, s1 and s2.

Comment: Also, your `while` condition seems to be ineffective as `queue_empty(q1)==0` means `q1 is not empty`, which is always true, and `c1` and `c2` never change within the loop.

Comment: where should i update the changes to c1 and c2?

Comment: Wow. I'm impressed at the audacity of George Mason students. Posting "Here's my HW, what's wrong with it?" is a kind of cheating that's just shy of paying someone to do it for you. http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~kauffman/cs222/hw6.html I'm also impressed by the inability of StackOverflow users to recognize HW problems. When someone says "these are the only functions we are allowed to use," it's a pretty clear sign that they constrained by academia. I'll make sure to let other CS instructors know that they need to patrol StackOverflow and similar sites to prevent further shenanigans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `queue_pop()` where appropriate in your algorithm. Once you copy the card from a queue to a stack (via push) you need to remove it from your pile. In reality this should be part of the main-play of the game, not the intro (its the same, but you'll figure that out eventually), and you'll need to move *both* stacks of cards to the appropriate queue once a winner of a specific round is declared.

Anyway, get your pops in there.

```
int start_battle(queue *q1, queue *q2, stack *s1, stack *s2, FILE *logfile){    
    int warc =0;
    int i;
    stack_push(s1, queue_front(q1));
    queue_pop(q1); // no longer in this queue.
    stack_push(s2, queue_front(q2));
    queue_pop(q2); // no longer in this queue.
    card c1 = stack_top(s1);
    card c2 = stack_top(s2);
    while (c1.face==c2.face && queue_empty(q1)==0 && queue_empty(q2)==0) {        
        warc++;        
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if(queue_empty(q1)==0){
                stack_push(s1, queue_front(q1));
                queue_pop(q1);
            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if (queue_empty(q2)==0){
                stack_push(s2, queue_front(q2));
                queue_pop(q2);
            }    
        }       
   }

   return warc;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but these are the only functions we are allowed to use:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghbfdqb9l7erz5e/libcardlist.c

Comment: @Jenny Link up your output, and if needed, post more code (like the main run-loop). The code to actually play the game will be very similar to your startup loop (in fact, this loop is actually *part* of the actual game). The initial deck should likely be printed as well, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Chef has a set of NN slices of bread which he wants to arrange in stacks. The stacks should be stable. A stable stack is one in which the slices in a single stack are ordered by their radii in a strictly increasing order such that the top-most slice will have the smallest radius. For example, a stack of slices with radii [7, 4, 3][7,4,3] is stable, while a stack of slices with radii [3, 5, 2][3,5,2] is not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).